# List navigated by arrows in Javascript

Tags: javascript, navigation, keyboard

I need help with navigating by **li** using arrow keys. I tried do something like:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode==40) {
        document.getElementById("sugesstions").getElementsByTagName("li")[0].className="focus";
        return true;
    }
}
```

Of course now it is only select the first **li** but it is selected only when I am pressing key. If I don't press it is no selected anymore. I tried integrate few examples from stackoverflow but seems that function focus() doesn't work in my case. Don't know why.

Comment: *"seems that function `focus()` doesn't work in my case"* - It doesn't make sense to set the focus to an `<li>` element, because a user can't really interact with an `<li>` in the way that they can with form controls and anchors.

Comment: I know. But in some examples there was focus function on LI. That's why I am writing it. I'm beginner with JS so it is better to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I've done it! I think is kind of messy and it's probably can be done better but...

```
var sel;
document.onkeyup = function(e) { 
    var count = document.getElementById("getClient").children.length;
    if (e.keyCode==40) {
        if (sel==null) {
            document.getElementById("getClient").getElementsByTagName("li")[0].className+="focus";
            sel=0;
        } else if (sel>=0 && sel<count-1) {
            sel=sel+1;
            document.getElementById("getClient").getElementsByTagName("li")[sel].className+="focus";
        } else if (sel==count-1) {
            document.getElementById("getClient").getElementsByTagName("li")[0].className+="focus";
            sel=0;
        }
    } else if (e.keyCode==38) {
        if (sel==null) {
            sel=count-1;
            document.getElementById("getClient").getElementsByTagName("li")[sel].className+="focus";
        } else if (sel>0 && sel<count) {
            sel=sel-1;
            document.getElementById("getClient").getElementsByTagName("li")[sel].className+="focus";
        } else if (sel==0) {
            sel=count-1;
            document.getElementById("getClient").getElementsByTagName("li")[sel].className+="focus";
        }
    }
    return sel;
}
```